# Why isn't Dispatcher.BeginInvoke working when re-creating my WPF DataGrid columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid, begininvoke

I have a `DataGrid` with a set of columns dynamically generated for a range of dates, and bound to the grid with a custom dependency property,

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableColumnsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableColumns",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),
        typeof(DataGridAttachedProperties),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableColumnsPropertyChanged));
```

The `BindableColumnsPropertyChanged` contains the following code that is where the problems occur:

```
else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
{
    foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
    {
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
    }
}
else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
{
    foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.OldItems)
    {
        dataGrid.Columns.Remove(column);
    }
}
```

When I call my `InitColumns` method from the `RefreshCommand` code, on `dataGrid.Columns.Remove(column)` I get the error:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.
>   I fixed that by changing the `Remove` code to:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    dataGrid.Columns.Remove(column);
}));
```

Then I try again, and the `Remove` code works, but I obviously get the same error on the `dataGrid.Columns.Add(column)` line. I also change that:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}));
```

And I try running the refresh command again, again the new dispatched `Remove` still works, but now I get the same error, but withing the `BeginInvoke` delegate for the `dataGrid.Columns.Add(column)` call:

[image]

This I don't understand. It is surely the same thread that successfully removed the column, but now it looks like some new phantom thread is trying to add the column. Whatever could cause this?

Comment: I think there is maybe a timing problem. You're using the async BeginInvoke. Maybe two Dispatched Actions will run at same time and you get this exception. You could try using `Dipatcher.Invoke` instead or add some lock around your `DataGrid.Columns....` calls.

Comment: @WPFGermany Attractive and sensible ideas, thanks. Try them when I can.

Comment: Your last error happens on Add. But that doesn't mean Remove has no error. "again the new dispatched Remove still works" --- I don't think so. What if you comment dataGrid.Columns.Add(column) ?

Comment: @WPFGermany Plain old `Dipatcher.Invoke` does seem to work just fine. Put it in an answer and get the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is maybe a timing problem. You're using the async `BeginInvoke`. Maybe two Dispatched Actions will run at same time and you get this exception.
You could try using `Dipatcher.Invoke` instead or add some `Lock` around your `DataGrid.Columns` calls.

Comment: Yes, simply using `Dipatcher.Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke` was all that was required. Thank yopu.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you are manipulating an UI bound `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>` from a non UI thread. So using `Dispatcher` when handling `CollectionChanged` (as well as `PropertyChanged`) and applying the changes to the `DataGrid` is the correct way to go.

But why `Remove` works and `Add` doesn't?

It's not shown in the post, but I suspect that you are not only adding `DataGridColumn` descendants to your observable collection, but you are also **creating** (and initializing) them on a non UI thread, which would cause the described behavior.

It's because the [`DataGridColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) class inherits (through [`DependencyObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx)) the [`DispatcherObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject(v=vs.110).aspx). The `DispatcherObject` class (hence the derived classes) stores the current thread `Dispatcher` inside its **constructor**, and then uses that dispatcher to verify that **each** dependency property access is done from the thread that created the object.

Shortly, the whole `DataGridColumn` creation and manipulation should happen on the UI thread. Locate the code that creates columns and make sure it executes on the UI thread by using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` and some of the `Dispatcher.Invoke` overloads.

P.S. Although the above is the most logical explanation I can think of, you can verify if the assumption is correct by modifying the posted code as follows:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    if (!column.CheckAccess())
    {
        // Houston, we've got a problem!
    }
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}));
```

and put a breakpoint inside the `if` statement.

Comment: I have considered creating a named template for the column, and only setting that in the non-UI code. Do you think that will be any better. Or maybe I can derive a 'special' text column, with the template name already set, so I don't have to do any initialisation off the UI thread.The template would only apply to my special column type.

Comment: If you can have column objects pre created, that will be fine. But I think first we need to make sure that this is the exact problem - I was kind of guessing logically, it could be much easier if you examine the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.Current.Dispatcher` will get you the `Dispatcher` of the current application. So calling `BeginInvoke` on that does not necessarily mean it will work: what if it is not that thread is not the owner of the control? After all, any thread could have created the control. Therefore, you should try and get the `Dispatcher` of the control and then call `BeginInvoke` on that:

```
YourControl.Dispatcher.Invoke();
```

Now that does not mean you can simply do this:

```
if (column.CheckAccess())
{
    // Great this thread has access so I will remove this column.
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

That check only tells you that the current thread owns `column` but not necessarily `dataGrid` and the `Columns` collection (this I am not too sure about but you have the code so you can simply try it). Therefore you will need to do this:

```
if (column.CheckAccess())
{
    if (dataGrid.CheckAccess())
    {
        // Code here. You may need to check `Columns` as well but like I said I am not sure about this one.
    }
    else
    {
        dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(/* code here */);
    }
}
else
{
    column.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(/* code here */);
}
```

Now you see that is going to make you go in circles so therefore, it is a good idea to create the parent ui control and its children on the same thread. At least that will help you figure out the issue and for the future you know not to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}));
```

instead of your code.

I think you are working with multiple UI threads, so you are getting this errors.

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid I have loads of threads all over the place. This was hacked together for a demo just an iota more than a wireframe, and I thought I see how far I could get to know async/await for keeping the UI responsive. It's been an experience.

Comment: Nope, same problem using `dataGrid.Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you create DataGridColumn on non-ui thread.

When  `dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);` is executed, internally DataGrid is trying to get new items' `DataGridColumn.DisplayIndex` dependency property value, and upon doing this DataGridColumn calls `CheckAccess` to verify current thread is a thread it was created on, and this test fails and results in exception thrown.

So it's DataGridColumn that throws exception.

I've created a little test project to check this ([see github](https://github.com/shorstok/wpf-misc/tree/DgWpfTest/)), specifically two methods which differ only with thread DataGridColumns are created on:

This one results in exception (creating columns on thread pool thread):

```
await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);    //detaching to thread pool thread

ViewModel.Columns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>(); //initializing colleciton in thread pool, but this gets marshalled by WPF

Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);  //wait for dispatched PropertyChanged to take effect

//creating cols in thread pool thread
var cols = new List<DataGridColumn>
{
    new DataGridTextColumn {Header = "test col 1", Binding = new Binding()},
    new DataGridTextColumn {Header = "test col 2", Binding = new Binding()}
};

//adding previously created columns - should throw
foreach (var dataGridColumn in cols)
    ViewModel.Columns.Add(dataGridColumn);
```

This one works ok (creating columns on UI thread):

```
//creating cols in UI thread
var cols = new List<DataGridColumn>
{
    new DataGridTextColumn {Header = "test col 1", Binding = new Binding()},
    new DataGridTextColumn {Header = "test col 2", Binding = new Binding()}
};

await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);    //detaching to thread pool thread

ViewModel.Columns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>(); //initializing colleciton in thread pool

Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { },DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);  //wait for dispatched PropertyChanged to take effect

//adding previously created columns - should succeed
foreach (var dataGridColumn in cols)
    ViewModel.Columns.Add(dataGridColumn);
```

I would suggest you to make this more MVVM-way, for example create a viewmodel class like ColumnViewModel with view-agnostic properties, bind ObservableCollection and in turn create actual DataGridColumns in your attached INotifyCollectionChanged implementation, e.g. instead of

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}));
```

you should do something like

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{   
     dataGrid.Columns.Add(CreateColumnFromViewModel(columnVm));
}));
```

In turn, you'll get

1. Your View decoupled from ViewModel and ViewModel that's not bound to concrete View implementation,
2. You can be sure your DataGridColumns are always created on UI thread

If you're interested, I could elaborate on this

Answer (score 0):

Putting it simple, create the `DataGridColumn` instances on the UI thread.

If you wanted to benefit from async/await, I would have gone with a more MVVM friendly approach:

- Instead of using `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>` I would have used a list of models that "describe" the required column such as `ObservableCollection<MyColumnDefinition>`
- Where `MyColumnDefinition` contains properties for creating a `DataGridColumn` such as: a value that maps to column types, binding path, width, etc.
- Then do the transformation from `MyColumnDefinition` to `DataGridColumn` inside the `PropertyChanged` handler
- You should still use the dispatcher when creating and adding `DataGridColumn` instances to the `DataGrid`'s `Columns` property

This way you should have no problem creating columns using something like:

```
await Task.Run(() => new MyColumnDefinition { ... });
```